# Parsing files in generic kernel extensions

Tags: c, xcode, macos, file-io, kernel-extension

Xcode's generic Kernel Extension requires file parsing.

For example, I want to read the contents of the A.txt file and save it as a variable. Just like you used FILE, fopen, EOF in c

As you can see, generic Kernel Extension can not include stdio.h, resulting in an error of use of undeclared identifier.

I am wondering if there is a way to parse a file in generic Kernel Extension like c.
(The following code can be used in Kernel Extension)

```
FILE *f;
char c;
int index = 0;
f = fopen(filepath, "rt");
while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF){
    fileContent[index] = c;
    index++;
}
fileContent[index] = '\0';
```

Comment: I'm wondering how to do file I / O in the kernel extension.

For example, it reads the contents of an A.txt file and prints it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I googled a bit and found e.g. [Kernel Extension development for macOS](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/430-macos-kext-development). I came to the conclusion that "loading a file in a KEXT", you got something wrong. If you need to bring data into the KEXT (e.g. for configuration) then the right approach seems to be either provide this data at start `kern_return_t Kext_start(kmod_info_t* ki, void* d);` or let the application set that data via _Kernel-user interaction (IO)_...

Comment: Also worth to be mentioned: _When you are trying to determine if a piece of code should be a KEXT, the default answer is generally **no**._ found in [Kernel Extension Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Extend/Extend.html). I assume, your question is regarding a toy project to learn how it works. Hence, I recommend to read the provided links to first learn for what a KEXT is good for (and for what not). IMHO, _it reads the contents of an A.txt file and prints it._ is not for what KEXTs are intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly *possible*. You'll need to do the following:

1. Open the file with `vnode_open()`. This will turn your path into a `vnode_t` reference. You'll need a VFS authorisation context; you can obtain the current thread's context (i.e. open the file as the user in whose process's context the kernel is currently running) with `vfs_context_create()` if you don't already have one.
2. Perform I/O with `vn_rdwr()`. (Reads & writes use the same function, just pass `UIO_READ` or `UIO_WRITE` as the second argument.)
3. Close the file and drop references to the vnode with `vnode_close()`. Possibly dispose of a created VFS context using `vfs_context_rele()`.

You'll want to look at the headerdocs for all of those functions, they're defined in `<sys/vnode.h>` in the Kernel.framework, and explaining every parameter exceeds the scope of a SO question/answer.

**Note:** As a commenter has already pointed out however, you'll want to make sure that opening files is really what needs to be done to solve whatever your problem is, particularly if you're newish to kernel programming. If at all unsure, I suggest you post a question along the lines of "I'm trying to do X, is reading the file in a kext really the best way forward?" where X is sufficiently high level, not "I need the contents of a file in the kernel" but *why*, and why a *file* specifically?

In various kernel execution contexts, file I/O may not be safe (i.e. may sometimes hang the system). If your kext loads early during boot, there might not be a file system yet. File I/O causes a *lot* to happen in the system, and can take a very long time in kernel terms - especially if you consider network file systems (including netboot environments!). If you're not careful, you might cause a bad user experience if the user is trying to eject a volume with a file your kext has open: the user has no way of resolving this, the OS can only suggest specific apps to close, it can't reach deep into your kext. Plus, there's the usual warnings about kernel programming in general: just because it can be done in the kernel, doesn't mean it should be. It's more the opposite: *only if it can't be done any other way should it be done in a kext.*

Comment: When you say Kernel.framework which contains sys/vnode.h file, where should I have to look at? Is it in the root file system ? or in the xnu source repository?

Comment: @ruach The full path will be something like `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Headers/sys/vnode.h` but you can get there much more easily from within Xcode by ⌘-clicking on the `#include <sys/vnode.h>` directive in your kext source and selecting "Jump to Definition"